# jQuery Class is not adding after division refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery code where when a `button-refresh` is clicked, `table-data` table is refreshed.
But when it is refreshed, the class `negative` is not adding to the `td`

Below is the code

```
$("#button-refresh").click(function(){
    $("#table-data").load("index.php #table-data");
    $("td[name=td-total").each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
        var num = parseFloat(text);
        if (num < 0) {
          $(this).addClass("negative");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it just me or am I seeing much hatred in StackOverflow lately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use callback method of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$("#button-refresh").click(function(){
  $("#table-data").load("index.php #table-data", function() {
    $("td[name=td-total").each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      var num = parseFloat(text);
      if (num < 0) {
        $(this).addClass("negative");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**AJAX calls are asynchronous**, therefore the `.load()` method provides a second argument that is a success callback:

`.load("url", function(response, status, xhr) {`

inside the callback place the code you want to run once AJAX responded

```js
$("#button-refresh").click(function(){
  $("#table-data").load("index.php #table-data", function(r, s, x) {
    $("td[name=td-total").each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      var num = parseFloat(text);
      if (num < 0) {
        $(this).addClass("negative");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/